# Automating Spin Up/Down Of AMIs using Terraform/Terragrunt

Tags: terraform

This may seem silly, but I've been looking for instructions/tutorial on how to automate an Amazon AMI to teardown/up on a schedule. This is because we have non-production servers used for development that don't need to run 24/7. Any chance someone can assist or point me in the proper direction?

Comment: Do you mean to spin up an EC2 instance? An AMI is just the image and is deployed as an EC2 instance either directly or as part of an autoscaling group (ASG). Also, what have you attempted so far? Do you have some code that doesn't do what you want it to do? It would be useful if you could show the code and also any errors or explain why it doesn't achieve what you want.

Comment: Apologies. Still learning Amazon Web service terminology and such. I believe the answer below could be what I need. If not, I will certainly will come back and add more information. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I do it;

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg_morning" {
  count                  = "${var.schedule_enabled}"
  scheduled_action_name  = "${upper(var.environment)}-${app}-AM-Schedule"
  min_size               = 1
  max_size               = 1
  desired_capacity       = 1
  recurrence             = "${var.schedule_am}"
  autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.app.name}"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_schedule" "asg_evening" {
  count                  = "${var.schedule_enabled}"
  scheduled_action_name  = "${upper(var.environment)}-${var.app}-PM-Schedule"
  min_size               = 0
  max_size               = 0
  desired_capacity       = 0
  recurrence             = "${var.schedule_pm}"
  autoscaling_group_name = "${aws_autoscaling_group.app.name}"
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I need. I appreciate your time.

Comment: If it helps solve your problem (assuming you've tried it and it works for you) then you should consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)